# Mount file system of a file to a virtual disk in Windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, mount

I am trying to create an application that is able to mount a file into a virtual drive in Windows using Java, much like mounting an ISO file into virtual DVD drive. As far as I can see the available library for Java only supports Linux or can only create in memory file system like Google's Jimfs. Is there any library I can use to develop the app in Java?

Comment: Without knowing what type of file you want to read as a file system, your question is too general to answer.

Comment: @VGR I am not sure what kind of file but I suppose it can be any file types  just like the container created by TrueCrypt but I don't think it would be any kind of media drive type like ISO or so. Do you have any recommendation of file type that can be used for mounting in Windows?

Comment: Are you planning on writing to this file system?  If it’s read-only, I would use a zip file.  Java lets you create a file system from a zip file;  see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html .  (I think you can write to it as well, but I don’t know how reliable that is.)

Comment: @VGR actually I want to write to the file system dynamically but I think using zip file it will require to create a new zip file each time there is write operation into it (not sure about the systematically but I reckon it would require unzip and zip file again).

Comment: I’m not clear on the benefit of keeping your files archived all the time.  Why not just unpack them when the application starts, and rebuild the archive when you exit?

Comment: @VGR basically this will be a "directory" that will store any files shared over cloud based application and I would like to make it secure with VeraCrypt or TrueCrypt ideas in mind (which are developed in C++) by mounting a file into a directory that stored all the shared files. If it is using archite file type like zip I was thinking that it could be accessed by any zip application or even the Windows explorer itself that will be not very secure.